# is there any way to display all my products in group product on one page in admin dashboard

Tags: magento2, collection, admin-panel, product-list, grouped-products

Basically this is my group product 
[image]

and this is how we can see all of child products
[image]

Now I dont want that previous and next button i just want all my products in list comes in one page or tab.
help me to solve this problem.

Comment: yes may be you can.

Comment: If you have any idea can you please guide me

Comment: yes I can idea.

Comment: we need to change code

Comment: Yes please i can change in code.

Comment: i have done several changes in Grouped.php ,Grouped.phtml  in module-grouped-product but its working.

Comment: ok can you share me what you changed

Comment: In Grouped.php i have changed Sort order 20 to 100 but i doesnt worked i think im trying in wrong way. please guide me to solve this .

Comment: ok can you share image what you did before

Comment: Yes  https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Ttujo6EabfyAYowyM1J2BDNsMoxATpq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i had changed this 20 to 100 but it doesnt worked

Comment: ok I will chek and update you

Comment: just share me that file path too

Comment: Yes sure i hope ill get solution from you thanks

Comment: here is the path magento_root/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Grouped.php

Comment: magento_root/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/grouped.phtml check this file also

Comment: you got solution?

Comment: no I will let you know ok

Comment: Yes sure im waiting

Comment: ok please or drop me personal msg

Comment: Can you share your email or skype?? i dont know how to msg in stack exchange

Comment: hmm please check my profile